# GPO and Security Groups in multiple domain

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain, security-groups, trust-relationship

I have 2 forests, each with one domain with a bidirectional trust.

I have created security groups in forest A, to access folders, where I have added both users from forest A and B, the accesses are working for every user of both forest.

I have created a gpo in order to automatically map the drives. The policy has been created and applied to forest A with item level targeting to the different security groups.

The policy works for all users of forest A, but not for users of forest B, the drives are not mapped.

How can I let the policy to be applied also on forest/domain B ? Is it possible ?

I have even tried to recreate the same gpo on domain B but there I cannot add the security groups from domain A, but under level targeting-> locations I see only one domain, not both.

I hope my issue is easy to understand :)

Thanks

Comment: Group Policy does not apply to accounts in a different domain.

Comment: I believe at a minimum the following policy would need to be enabled: System > Group Policy > Allow cross-forest user policy and roaming user profiles

Comment: @GregAskew the policy you mention has to be enabled on both domains, right ?

Comment: @chart: I haven't used it so I'm not sure. I suspect this is for users that may be on a system in another forest to apply user policies from their home/account forest. My experience has been most people make a copy of a GPO in each forest/domain where it's needed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Semicolon said, Group Policys do not apply to accounts in a different domains. You need to create a GPO in both domains. If the group in Domain B does not show up in the GPO editor, triple check your Domain trust and that ouy can actually use both groups in both domains.